# How to convert INR to USD before passing to paypal in opencart

Tags: php, paypal, opencart, payment-gateway, currency

I have tried this below code in `catalog/controller/payment/pp_standard.php`. it works fine. For example, My product rate is 2450 INR. When I choose paypal option it would convert the INR rate into USD rate and then it would redirect to paypal.com successfully.

But, I have enabled paypal express checkout also. So, When I choose paypal express checkout option it doesn't redirect to paypal.com. because of currency problem (I get currency is not supporrted error). How do I convert the INR currency to USD currency before passing to paypal in opencart?

**Note** : I need a solution for Paypal Express Checkout `catalog/controller/payment/pp_express.php` & `catalog/model/payment/pp_express.php`

```
$currencies = array(
                'AUD',
                'CAD',
                'EUR',
                'GBP',
                'JPY',
                'USD',
                'NZD',
                'CHF',
                'HKD',
                'SGD',
                'SEK',
                'DKK',
                'PLN',
                'NOK',
                'HUF',
                'CZK',
                'ILS',
                'MXN',
                'MYR',
                'BRL',
                'PHP',
                'TWD',
                'THB',
                'TRY'
             );

             if (!in_array(strtoupper($this->currency->getCode()), $currencies))
             {
                $order_info['currency_code'] = 'USD';
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying the same code after:

```
$order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
```

and adding one extra line,

```
$order_info['total'] = $this->currency->format($order_info['total'], $order_info['currency_code'], false, false);
```

should work just fine.

PS. I have not tested it, but you should be fine :D

Comment: I have added this line in `catalog/controller/payment/pp_express.php`. still, it doesn't redirect to paypal site..

Comment: you should add the code you highlighted in your question and afterwards that extra line, the idea is after you get the data in $order_info you convert currency (via your code in the question) and price (via the extra code i mentioned), that's all the data you need to convert (if i am not mistaken :D).